# Smart Tag Shortcut - 2017 Community Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2017

I'm using the 2017 Community Edition of Visual Studio, and I can't figure out how to toggle the "Smart Tag" feature (helper, auto-fix, suggestion tool).

It normally appears as a tiny square you can hover on, once first hovering over an error. This interaction is really annoying, and there should be a  keyboard shortcut for it, but I can't find it.

The keyboard shortcuts that work in other versions of VS for Windows etc. don't work here. I also can't find any type of key binding under the settings for a "smart tag".

[Picture Example: The small smart tag in VS 2017 for macOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8wY7.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is "Quick Fix..."
You can use the shortcut <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd> (also shown as <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⏎</kbd>)

You can modify the shortcut in Preferences -> Enviroment -> Key Bindings -> Refactoring -> Quick Fix..